# Selecting Values from one table based on another table for stored procedute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
select 
    assn as Association, count(id) as Total
from 
    Farmers
where 
    assn is not null
group by 
    assn
order by 
    assn asc
```

Which generates this table:

[image]

Can anyone assist me in populating the `Association` column above with values in association column from this second table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
SELECT f.assn AS AssociationId,
       a.Association,
       COUNT(f.id) AS Total
FROM Farmers f
     INNER JOIN YourSecondTable a ON f.assn = a.id
WHERE assn IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY assn,
         a.Association
ORDER BY assn ASC;
```

Replace YourSecondTable with the name of your second table

Comment: This code gives me 2 Association columns. I would just like with the BSCFA etc

Comment: just remove "f.assn AS AssociationId," from the code

Comment: Thanks I did that.